# Sequential flow of tcp packets to server using websockets

Tags: c#, tcp, websocket

I can post my code here if people want me to but this could be a simple quick answer so i have not done so yet.

I have a c# desktop app.

It sends information to my server using web sockets.

the information contains a time-stamp of when that information was created. It is sent in time-stamp order to my server.

On my server I am comparing the current time-stamp to the previous time-stamp.  There is a quite a vast number of information that is being received in a sporadic order.

I had thought that TCP was supposed to retain the order.  Am I wrong? Is there a way to ensure delivery in the correct order or do I have to write code on my server to re-order it all?

I am sending information 20 times a second.

Thanks

Comment: It could be a concurrency issue - while the messages might be coming in at the right order (TCP level), the events in the websocket queue might be executed in a different order than expected by either the client or the sever... For instance, although a `send` was scheduled in your app, it might execute asynchronously after a later `send`. Also the server might queue a number of `on_message` events and they might be executed asynchronously in a different order than received/expected. We need more code to know...

Comment: That is good thinking. I am using flek web sockets. I will post that code when I am back. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a synchronicity issue related to publishing to the Redis server.

- Testing on my machine showed that using a browser and a basic websocket server, messages would be both received and dealt with in sequential order.
- Deploying this demo app to viaduct.io (one remote app) showed that the message order was preserved.
- Connecting the websocket server to Redis and using two remote implementations (one on Heroku and one on viaduct.io), broke the message order.

This makes me believe it's a synchronicity issue (race conditions related to the Redis server publish access) on the Plezi framework or - more likely (since you have the same issue) - synchronicity issues related to the Redis library implementation (Plezi's Redis mutex is only active while establishing a connection. afterwards, Plezi relies on the Redis implementation for thread safety).

---

The test app:

I checked the message order using [Plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) (a Ruby websocket server framework) and a browser.

In Plezi, I used the simple chatroom app that's automatically created when using:

```
 plezi mini appname
```

The app broadcasted all the incoming messages to all the connected websocket clients (including the sender).

On the Redis, implementation, the broadcasting was using Redis to connect the two remote applications. I used Plezi's auto-redis feature:

```
 ENV['PL_REDIS_URL'] = my_redis_url # it has my password, I don't share ;-)
```

I always tested using two browser windows.

In one browser window, after establishing and testing the websocket connection (so the message `testing` showed on both browser windows), I executed:

```
 for(i=0; i<100; i++) {websocket.send("message number: " + i)}
```

In the other browser window I reviewed the messages received manually.

Both the local and the non-redis remote implementation preserved the message order.

On the remote implementation using Redis, both browser windows (also the one sending the data) showed the message order being garbled. This means that race conditions related to the Redis server were causing the broadcasting to wait and broke the order of **transmission**.

The order of reception matched the order of transmission (the subscribed thread didn't experience race conditions and so the message order was preserved).

I should point out that Plezi is multithreaded, this means that message handling is concurrent. I assume that if only one thread was in control, race conditions wouldn't apply and the message order would be preserved - but I didn't test this.

Comment: Wow, very comprehensive!

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSimpson .